# Converting an algorithm from Java to NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

What are the implications for converting a Java algorithm to NDK in order to protect it? This Java algorithm takes data as input and outputs processed data. That's it. It does not interact with the UI in any way.

1. Will the converted algorithm cause compatibility issues on some of the Android devices?
2. Since the algorithm is converted to c++, does that mean it cannot be decompiled but can only be disassembled?
3. Is there any tool that allows me to convert this Java algorithm to NDK without me writing the algorithm myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Java code is compiled into byte code, which is then run on the JVM, while C/C++ code is compiled into machine code. I don't think it's reasonable to convert Java code to C/C++ because of security reasons, it's mostly done because the code written in C/C++ is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know preventing decompilation is one of the main reasons to use NDK along with improving performance as mentioned by Andrej. When it comes to your questions:

1) You will have to make sure you compile your native code for all five supported ABIs, i.e. `x86`, `x86_64`, `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a`.

2) Nothing is 100% impossible to decompile, but chances that your native code will be successfully decompiled are a lot lower than decompiling java bytecode.

3) No you have to write C or C++ code yourself. However, headers containing the API you want to expose to Java can be generated by `javah`.

Android Studio makes it quite easy to write small native libraries and integrate them into existing projects, you need only very basic knowledge of CMake.

Comment: Good point! But I'm not sure what OP means by "algorithm" and whether Quixxi will be able to convert this whole algorithm to native code, so I won't edit my answer.

Comment: for 3) actually there is a [paid tool](https://quixxi.com/docs/platforms/android/) for mobile security based on JNI [thus Android NDK installation is NOT required] providing this automated functionality for jar files that can be later integrated in the target Android app following the linked instructions. Basically you upload your jar file receiving back a zip file including a .java class to access the native layer, a jniLibs folder with the shared objects files compiled for 4 ABIs and corresponding to your original library plus other utils classes [e.g. the one calling System.loadLibrary()]